# Reading the iPhone earphone socket or bluetooth (heartrate measurement)

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-audio

I would like to program an iOS App which uses a heartrate-Monitor like the 
[iOximeter](http://safeheartus.com/ioximeter) or a runtastic bluetooth belt. I would prefer the iOximeter, but the belt would also be okay.
Are there any Frameworks I can use. I couldn't find one - maybe because I'm new to iOS development. I've just experiences in C++, HTML5, Java,...
Are there any tutorials (links, books,...) beside the apple ones I could use? Especially about my topic?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS framework to use for reading data from a BLE heart monitor is Core Bluetooth.  There are plenty of tutorials around on using Core Bluetooth from Objective C or Swift.  (But likely none in C++ or Java.)